# Sagepay/.net/Error Response

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse, opayo

Sending a request to the sagepay test server and get the following response:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive."

The most obvious question:

**1. Do I have to set up an SSL for requests/responses? (bearing in mind this is just a test/dev environment)**

**2. I am using WebRequest and passing VPSProtocol,TxType,Vendor, Crypt vals in the Header
3. Method is POST
4. I have included**

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't (see below)
2. It sounds like you are integrating with the Form protocol - don't pass these values as a header - they should be query string parameters. Redirect your customer to the page (eg: https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp?VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=PAYMENT&vendor=werwer&Crypt=sdfsdf) which should just perform a get, and you should get the Payment pages (or at least an error, which you can troubleshoot).

Comment: Still didn't work. "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"  I've built my uri as described above (and the Crypt is in plain text), use method POST, then get response (HttpWebResponse) .

Comment: Following the instructions at https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/25041/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf?token=buxdjpRBiyWKQ_Ky_TFWSKdtCJ1sdzbs_A0UGgm29d8 the Crypt val is encrypted but same error message.

Comment: In the instructions it states: "using the provided password as both
the key and initialisation vector" as part of the encryption process. Is this the Sagepay a/c login password? What is the initialisation vector?

Comment: Using var passToBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("55a51621a6648525");
                    myRijndael.Key = passToBytes;
                    myRijndael.IV = passToBytes; then encrypting the string with the Key/IV then prepending with "@" to add to sagepay url

Comment: Should be - System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes([Form Integration Password])